# I can't use tensorflow 2.5.0 in google colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I install python 3.8. in colab .but i can't install tensorflow 2.5.0.
I want to use "https://github.com/kairess/Mask_RCNN/tree/master" but it need to use tensorflow 2.5.0.

Comment: Hi @help, Google Colab has upgraded to python version 3.10 and the fallback runtime is not available to downgrade python version to 3.8 for the tensorflow 2.5. Could you please try again by running the code with any of latest `tensorflow 2.8 - 2.13` supported by existing `python 3.10` in Google Colab.